Automatic installation of Roots Updates
You can use the registry parameter to redirect the source of root certificate updates:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot\AutoUpdate
"RootDirURL"="d:\......."

Is it possible to automatically distribute certificates of intermediate certification authorities in this way?
